# Algebraic Fundamentals

Tags: linear-algebra

**Below is a Question From Algebraic Fundamentals.**

> Compute $|p^3+q^3+r^3|$ independent of $p,q,r$ if the variables are distinct integers summing to zero.

*Need Help Finding the solution.*

Comment: What is the set $I$?

Comment: What is $I$????

Comment: I is the set for INTEGERS

Comment: Some kind of context would be nice for this - otherwise the problem is quite vague.

Comment: please follow [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question) before posting this kind of vague question

Comment: Is this problem from a book? If so what book, what page?

Comment: "I is the set of integers"  That is *very* unconventional.  Nearly every mathematician in the entire world uses $\mathbb Z$ and even those that don't will understand it.

Comment: Your question has no solution and seems bogus, double check the statement.

Answer (score 2):

This expression is not independent of $p,q,r$. Consider the counter example

$$|1^3+2^3-3^3|=18$$ and $$|1^3+3^3-4^3|=36.$$

---

If the question is about the minimum achievable value, then $0$ is obtained with $(p,q,r)=(n,0,-n)$ for any $n\ne0$, and permutations.